# Velocity problem hurry

Tags: velocity

Particle A moves at a constant velocity of  = 3m/s along a straight line of  = 30m. Particle A moves at a constant velocity of  = 3m/s
At the moment passing through, particle B starts at rest from the origin and moves at a constant acceleration of  = 0.4 m/s2 in the direction of the  axis and . Find each  for A and B to meet each other, along with the process of solving it. At this time, find the time it took for the two particles to meet.

Comment: In your question, when does the particle B starts moving? and what is the initial position of A in the beginning?